# How to add model attribute fields by monkey patching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know already how to add (include, prepend) **methods** into the class. But how to add **attributes**? For example i would like to patch core model by adding it **has_one** field, how am I supposed to do it? Thanks in advance.

E.x

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redmine::SafeAttributes
  include Redmine::NestedSet::ProjectNestedSet

  # Specific overridden Activities
  has_many :time_entry_activities
  has_many :memberships, :class_name => 'Member', :inverse_of => :project
  # Memberships of active users only
  has_many :members,
           lambda { joins(:principal).where(:users => {:type => 'User', :status => Principal::STATUS_ACTIVE}) }
```

I'd like to add one more has_many / has_one field not editing this class - which is in projects core, but as monkey patching -> include one more has_many from plugin directory

Comment: What do you mean by "core model"?
An example would be helpful to understand the context.

Comment: do you need to use the same `Project` class? one way might be by creating a new class that inherits from `Project`, like `ExtendedProject` or something

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
    base.class_eval do
      unloadable
      has_many :project_descriptions
    end
  end
  Project.send(:include, Module::Patches::ProjectPatch)
```

Adding fields to class, *base* here stands for included class, *class_eval* is evaluated in the context of that class.
More info on class_eval, instance_eval on 
https://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval/